# how can i count duplicates in a list and change the item value

Tags: c#

I have a program that generates 3 lists based on the contents of a text file. Now I want to look at a list and if there's an item in it more than once, I'd like to change the value to "number in list x item" and remove the duplicates from the list.

Here is the code I use to open and split up the file into the lists:

```
    private void open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inputFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
         var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(inputFile.FileName));
         while (!reader.EndOfStream)
             {
                 string line = reader.ReadLine();
                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
                 if (line.StartsWith("#main"))
                 {
                     deck = "main";
                 }
                 if (deck == "main")
                 {
                     if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
                     {
                         int cardid = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0));
                         MainDeck.Items.Add(Program.CardData[cardid].Name);
                     }
                 }
                 if (line.StartsWith("#extra"))
                 {
                     deck = "extra";
                 }
                 if (deck == "extra")
                 {
                     if (!line.StartsWith("#extra") && !line.StartsWith("!side"))
                     {
                         int cardid = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0));
                         ExtraDeck.Items.Add(Program.CardData[cardid].Name);
                     }
                 }

                 if (line.StartsWith("!side"))
                 {
                     deck = "side";
                 }
                 if (deck == "side")
                 {
                     if (!line.StartsWith("!side"))
                     {
                         int cardid = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0));
                         SideDeck.Items.Add(Program.CardData[cardid].Name);
                     }
                 }
            }
         reader.Close();
         GenerateCode();
        }
    }
```

In other words say the item `"hello"` is in the list 3 times: I want to change it to be in the list only once and say `"3x hello"`.

Comment: Create a counter based on the word you are looking for and write to the file CountVariable + "x" +  Hello based on the other comment I doubt that you would understand Linq not to mention the comment does not address your question

Comment: You can set the counter for each value and check if counter is greater than zero don't add to the list just increase the counter on match found

Comment: will that work for multiple words as i need it to put it in for every item in the list

Comment: If you understand Linq then that would be your best and quickest way to accomplish see `Tim Schmelter` answer straight forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Distinct` to remove the duplicates:

```
MainDeck = MainDeck.Distinct().ToList();
ExtraDeck = ExtraDeck.Distinct().ToList();
SideDeck = SideDeck.Distinct().ToList();
```

If you want to count the duplicates first:

```
int mainDeckDups = MainDeck.Count - MainDeck.Distinct().Count();
int extraDeckDups = ExtraDeck.Count - ExtraDeck.Distinct().Count();
int sideDeckDups = SideDeck.Count - SideDeck.Distinct().Count();
```

If you really want to show how many times an item was in the list you could use `Enumerable.GroupBy`, e.g.:

```
var mainDeckGroups = MainDeck.GroupBy(s => s)
    .Select(g => new { Item = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
foreach (var dup in mainDeckGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}x {1}", dup.Count, dup.Item);
// other lists ...
```

Comment: im trying this but getting an error does not contain a definition for distinct

Comment: @outlaw1994: If these are `ListBoxes` instead of `List<T>`(as i've assumed) you have to cast the items to string if possible, e.g. `MainDeck.Items.Cast<string>()`

Comment: @outlaw1994: What is the problem? Do you add the duplicate-result to the ListBox as well, is that desired? You could clear the ListBox first, then add all the unique items.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var g = MainDeck.Items.GroupBy(i => i).Select(x => x.Count() +"x " + x.Key);
```

You can filter it out if you want to count only the word "main" there. Follow the same for other lists..

The query is not evaluated at that point. Do a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to let that happen on `g`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve order of items in the list (assuming list contains the possible duplicates)

`var data = list.Select(r => result.Count(i => i == r) + "x " + r).ToList();`

and just slightly modify it to have "Hello" instead of "1x Hello".

Comment: i want it to say 1x on single items as well how would i add this in

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as well.

```
var list = new List<string> { "Hello", "World", "Hello", "Great", "World" };

var query = list.GroupBy(s => s)
        .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Then,

```
var resultList = query.Select(result => string.Format("{0}x {1}", result.Count, result.Value)).ToList();
```

or above code can be replaced as below for more clarity

```
foreach (var result in query)
    resultList.Add(string.Format("{0}x {1}", result.Count, result.Value));
```

Hope it helps.